# How can I develop an agent to notify user

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, wcf, agent

I would like to develop a program (an agent) that will run on the user's desktop. It has to communicate with a web service periodically then if a state changes it will notify the user in a notification balloon.

Can I do a winforms or wpf project? (that will both communicate with the web service and notify the user)

Or should I do separately a windows service that will firstly communicate with the web service and then communicate with another standalone winforms app that will notify the user?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it an application that runs within a company network? All the installations on the same OS? Tell us a bit more about it.

Comment: Yes in a company network and the same operating system

Comment: How do you intend to deploy it?

Comment: with a setup. the user will have to install the application. Then he will be able to receive some notifications depending on the state of the web service

Comment: @user3409988 First of all why you want to notify the user on Web service availability ? Is this service consumed by any application ?

Comment: no the web service returns some data and when there is some new it will notify the user. The program will check periodically the web service response and notifies if there is new data.

Answer (score 0):

**Periodically fetching status through service**

You can implement an executable(Console) application which should have the logic to invoke the web service to fetch the status. You can use [windows task scheduler](http://www.7tutorials.com/advanced-users-task-creation-task-scheduler) to execute this exe periodically.

There are many task scheduler wrapper libraries are available, Use could use any of them based on your need.

- [Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper](https://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/)
- [Quartz Job Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/)

**Notifying user**

If the status is changed then you can notify the user through any User interface, this can be WinForm or WPF application. When the exe which is initiated by the task scheduler finds a status change, it will execute the UI application that you have created to notify the user.

If you need only a single Form to notify the user then Windows Form should be enough unless you want to show any fancy UI using WPF.

***Why Windows Service might not be a good choice***

It's actually easy to use a windows service to periodically call the web service instead of using a Task scheduler, but the problem you will face with the windows service is that it can't easily communicate with user's desktop, that means it can't directly show/execute any User interface application on user desktop. You will end up writing a IPC(Inter Process Communication) mechanism to communicate with any UI application from windows service.

Comment: Is it possible to put all the scheduler inside wpf?

Comment: Like starting a wpf app -> launching scheduler in the main method -> notify by showing a pop up window